# How to close Browser Tab After Submitting a Form?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
    /* ... SQL EXECUTION TO UPDATE DB ... */
?>

<form method  = "post"
      action  = "<?=$_SERVER['php_self']?>" 
      onSubmit= "window.close();">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  <input type="reset"  value="reset" />
</form>
```

I would like to close page after submitting the form. After running the above code the page is closed after clicking submit button, but the SQL doesn't execute.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
<?php    
    /* ... SQL EXECUTION TO UPDATE DB ... */

    echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
?>
```

and Remove the `window.close()` from the form `onsubmit` event

Comment: maybe change it to `echo "<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>`

Comment: That **did** work form me, but it wasn't because i was using the `header('Location: text.php');` function before i'm trying to close it, so in case you are using a `header` but the `window.close()` script in the PHP page that you are redirecting to... (`text.php` in my example)... Hope this helps.

Comment: year 2018: doesnt work anymore in chrome or firefox - some security issues

Answer (score 11):

Remove `onsubmit` from the `form` tag. Change this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

To:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name='btnSub' />
```

And write this:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSub']))
    echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
```

Answer (score 5):

Window.close( ) does not work as it used to. Can be seen here:

[window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

In my case, I realized that I didn't need to close the page. So you can  redirect the user to another page with:

```
window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use the same page as the action, you cannot use `onSubmit="window.close();"` as it will close the window before the response is received. You have to dinamycally output a JS snippet that closes the window after the SQL data is processed. It would however be far more elegant to use another page as the form action.

Answer (score 1):

try `onsubmit="submit(); window.close()"`

Answer (score 1):

This worked brilliantly for me, :

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `table` (...or put your preferred sql stuff)" 
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
 if($result){
  // If everything runs fine with your sql query you will see a message and then the window
  //closes
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Successful!")';
        echo '</script>';
        echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
        }
 else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Problem with database or something!")';
        echo '</script>';           
        }
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem imo.
I am trying to build a small registration-system for larger events. The registration happens by scanning QR-codes ("tickets"), and I am trying to minimalize amounts of clicks. The alert will still require my registration team to do this extra interaction (confirm/ok the alert)!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the event `onsubmit` is triggered before the form is submitted.

Remove your `onSubmit` and output that JavaScript in your PHP script after you have processed the request. You are closing the window right now, and cancelling the request to your server.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this methods](https://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/ClosingWindowsNotOpenedByJS.html)

```
window.open(location, '_self').close();
```